# How do you share info between two or more worksheets embedded in a PowerPoint presentation

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerpoint

In Excel, it is easy to link cells on sheets within a workbook or even between separate files.

Is it possible to do the same thing between two or more  Excel worksheets which are embedded on to PPT slides?

I've defined a named range in one spreadsheet but there is no obvious way to reference/find that range within the spreadsheet on another slide.  Am I missing something obvious here?

I'm hoping that I do not need to use VBA (though I will if that is the only option).

Comment: why don't you just do you need between the two sheets in the actual XL files, then refresh he links in the ppt presentation?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman... long story.  In a nutshell, a legacy document that I've inherited.  The organization wants a single PPT file rather than a PPT and separate XLS files.  This means that you have to enter the same info into the embedded spreadsheets on separate slides in the deck.  I'd like to streamline things a bit.

Comment: Not possible, unfortunately.  Even if you embed different bits of content from a single spreadsheet, you one copy of the entire workbook in PPT for each embed. The two won't talk to one another.  It should be do-able one way or another via VBA, but it wouldn't be a learner's project.  IF you can activate two embedded sheets at once (and I don't know if you can) you could probably step through a cell at a time and update the contents of one spreadsheet with that of another.

Answer (score 0):

If you looking for a vba solution, this may help you get started: 
Update information within unrelated excel objects inserted in slides of a presentation
http://skp.mvps.org/ppt00040.htm#4